# Keras: unable to extract layer output while pushing layers back to model

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have a Keras classification network with last two layers as Dense and activation respectively. I popped the layers from the model as :

```
activationlayer=classifier.layers.pop()
denselayer=classifier.layers.pop()
```

Then I pushed the layers back into the model:

```
outt1=denselayer(classifier.layers[-1].output)
outt=activationlayer(outt1)
classifier=Model(classifier.input,outt)
```

Now while indexing the output of dense layer I get error:

```
classifier.layers[-2].output

Error: Layer out2 has multiple inbound nodes, hence the notion of "layer output" is ill-defined.
```

Comment: Seems like you need to call the exact input node you want to call for your output with layers.get_output_at(0) . See more here: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#the-concept-of-layer-node

Comment: Using classifier.get_output_at(-2) it gives Index error: list index out of range.

Comment: You created a branch in your model, get the output at 0 for the original branch, at 1 for the new branch.

Comment: @DanielMöller I did not understand. Can you please clarify.

Comment: Just try  `layer.get_output_at(0)` or `layer.get_output_at(1)`, one of them will work. --- Keras models are not lists where you can add/remove layers. They're forming a whole graph connecting tensors that are persistent. You created new tensors with outputs of tensors that were alread used. You transformed your "sequential" model in a "tree" and you need to choose from which branch you are getting the tensors now.